# Tracking Android installs via Google Play Source/ Medium from website

Tags: android, google-analytics, google-play

I am trying to track installs of an Android app via the Google Play store and which came from my site. I have the following links on my site (example.com):

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.example.android&referrer=utm_source%3Dexample.com%26utm_medium%3Dreferral%26utm_content%3Dhome%26utm_campaign%3Dapps

I have also linked my Analytics account to my Google Play account.

Alas, all the reports on my Analytics give me a Source/ Medium of: (direct) / (none)

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found out that my configuration above is correct. What was missing is to configure my app to receive that information from Google Play: (https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v2/campaigns)

```
<!-- Used for install referral measurement-->
<service android:name="com.google.analytics.tracking.android.CampaignTrackingService"/>
<receiver android:name="com.google.analytics.tracking.android.CampaignTrackingReceiver" android:exported="true">
  <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER" />
  </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Google will only provide you with sampling on your reports (since only Google should see the full picture) so you will need some "juice" data before you can actually see anything.